# checkbox $.change is being triggered by itself and looping because it is being modified inside $.change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes that when you click ONE, they should ALL be checked.

When a user clicks one checkbox, it checks all the other checkboxes starting with that class name. What I want is for the user to click a checkbox, and `$(".atpSelections").change` is triggered **only once** per click.

Here's the code:

```
        $(".atpSelections").change(function() {
            console.log("CHANGED");

            //Check ALL other checkboxes starting with that class name:
            var className = $(this).attr("class");
            className=className.replace("atpSelections ", "");
            className=className.trim();
            className=className.split("-");

            //Get current checkbox state
            var currentState = $(this).attr("checked");

            //Now loop through all other checkboxes starting 
            //with the same class name and check them:
            $("input[class*='"+className[0]+"-']").each(function(i){
                    //THIS IS TRIGGERING "$(".atpSelections").change"!!
                    if(currentState && currentState=="checked")
                    {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    }else
                    {
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });
        });
```

## The Problem

The **problem** is that when the user clicks one checkbox, the `$(".atpSelections").change` method gets triggered over and over because `$(this).prop('checked', true);` triggers `$(".atpSelections").change` again, and it just goes round and round.

So 1 click to a checkbox triggers 100s "change" events, when I only want it triggered **once.**

***How do I alter the checkbox's state inside `$(".atpSelections").change` without triggering `$(".atpSelections").change` again?***

## Attempts

I tried changing `$(".atpSelections").change` to `$(".atpSelections").click` but it had the same issue. I think `$(this).prop('checked', true);` triggers the `click` event.

## Solution

I used @James 's answer and changed

`var currentState = $(this).attr("checked");`

to

`var currentState = $(this).prop("checked") ? "checked" : "";`

and it worked perfectly! Thanks.

**Here's the JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/zL7amo0y/

Comment: Programmatically changing checked property doesn't triggers change event. Can you share HTML? As of now you code is mess

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question, create stacksnippets to demonstrate issue?

Comment: `currentState` doesn't contain what you expect, use `var currentState = $(this).prop("checked") ? "checked" : "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your currentState variable. Please do a console.log on it. I'm guessing it's undefined?

Below is your code fixed in both jQuery and Vanialla JS.

JQuery:

```js
       $(".atpSelections").change(function() {

            var currentState = $(this).prop("checked");
            console.log(currentState);

            $("input[name='checkboxToCheck']").each(function(i){
                    if(currentState)
                    {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    }else
                    {
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm">
   <label for="checkbox1">Main Checkbox:</label>
   <input class="atpSelections" value="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />

   <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox2:</label>
   <input name="checkboxToCheck" value="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />

   <label for="checkbox3">Checkbox3:</label>
   <input name="checkboxToCheck" value="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
  </form>
```

Vanilla JS:

```js
   var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox1")
   var checkboxToCheck = document.getElementsByName("checkboxToCheck");
   checkboxToCheck = [].slice.call(checkboxToCheck);

   function checkAllBoxes() {

    checkboxToCheck.forEach((element) => {
     if (checkbox.checked) {
      element.checked = true;
     } else {
      element.checked = false;
     }
    });

   }

   checkbox.addEventListener("change", checkAllBoxes);
```

```html
  <form name="myForm">
   <label for="checkbox1">Main Checkbox:</label>
   <input value="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />

   <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox2:</label>
   <input name="checkboxToCheck" value="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />

   <label for="checkbox3">Checkbox3:</label>
   <input name="checkboxToCheck" value="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking know what is your problem, I got it with a plugin of checkboxes too.

Try this

```
$(".atpSelections").on('change.custom', function(e) {
   console.log("CHANGED CUSTOM");

   //Check ALL other checkboxes starting with that class name:
   var className = $(this).attr("class");
   className=className.replace("atpSelections ", "");
   className=className.trim();
   className=className.split("-");

   //Get current checkbox state
   var currentState = $(this).attr("checked");

   //Now loop through all other checkboxes starting 
   //with the same class name and check them:
   $("input[class*='"+className[0]+"-']")
     .off('change.custom')
     .each(function(i){
       //THIS IS TRIGGERING "$(".atpSelections").change"!!
       if(currentState && currentState=="checked"){
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
       }else{
         $(this).prop('checked', false);
       }
   });
 });
```

Normally it's okay :)